# Bot save and send attachment with slash command with discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

[image: i]

I have seen this one,so I want to make it my self in discord.py.I tried:

```
upload_images = []

@client.tree.command(description='Image file')
@app_commands.describe(image_file="drag your image file here")
async def upload(image_file: discord.Attachment):---(error)
    await image_file.save(fp=upload_images, use_cached=True)---(error)


@client.tree.command(description='Send image file')
@app_commands.describe(send_image="Send random image from upload")
async def send(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    if upload_images:
        image_url = random.choice(upload_images)
        embed = discord.Embed(title='Here is your image', color=discord.Color.random()).set_image(url=image_url)
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)
    else:
        await interaction.response.send_message("No images uploaded yet.")
```

This is my code about to save attachment and send, but it give 2 issue:

```
1.TypeError: unknown parameter given: image_file(in async def upload)
2.Expected type 'Union[BufferedIOBase, PathLike]', got 'list' instead(in fp=upload_images)
```

Can you help me.Thank you so much,I appreciate your help!

Comment: You missed the interaction param in your @app_commands for upload command

Comment: when I add interaction another issue pop up in the async def send

Comment: `TypeError: unknown parameter given: send_image`

Comment: This is because you have `@app_commands.describe` which describe that your `send` command has a parameter called `send_image` but in your async function declaration, there is no parameter other than `interaction`

Comment: Oh I fix it because the send command don't need app.describe.And I need append to the list  not image_file.save